# How to set an openlayers preset to full screen?

Tags: 6, javascript

I am working on one of those sites that need a fullscreen dynamic map to show up as a background. This means the preset should be set to 100% height, but I can't get this to work. Is there a module for that? A jQuery snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at zzolo.org (the module mantainer's website) I learned that position:fixed (yes a CSS solution) can actually get this done.

Answer (score 0):

On the [OpenLayers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers) project page, it says:

"Behaviors
Map interactions like popups, zoom controls, editing, and fullscreen can be added via the UI and extended by other modules."

I don't have a site up and running with OL or I'd check it.

Comment: Yeah, I can add a button that enables fullscreen, but i can' turn it on by default :P

Comment: Oh here we go, try this js script:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/fullScreen.html